# How to Sliding to New Layout in Full Screen View?

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, layout

I am working on an application in android studio. The problem is, I'm using full screen view for the first time and I want to slide between layouts, horizontally I want a new page to come up every time the user scrolls. In the form of a loop.

Let me show you an example picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAjWb.png)

My layout code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFC300"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.ProjectAgilis1.FullscreenContainer"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="?attr/fullscreenTextColor"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<AnalogClock

    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Comment: please add your XML code in your question, not the code image.

Comment: Check [View Pager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide). It is used to slide between different layouts.